# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table in code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was try to add FK from `Guiders` table to `InvoiceDetails` table but I get this error while trying to run `update-database` :

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Guiders' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.InvoiceDetails_dbo.Guiders_GuidersID'.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Code:

```
public class TableBase
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceDetails : TableBase
{
    [Required]
    public int Qty{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Guid InvoicesID { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoices Invoices { get; set; }
    public Guid GuidersID  { get; set; }
    public virtual Guiders  Guiders { get; set; }
}

public class Guiders : TableBase
{
    public Guid GuidersID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guiders Guiders { get; set; }
    public Guid? ToursID { get; set; }
    public virtual Tours Tours { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory... what is the question?

Comment: The question how to solve this error ?

Comment: @kfix The error says "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Guiders'..." which is true. Your `Guiders` entity has no primary key. You should add one.

Comment: but please check my code the Guiders table it is inherent from Tablebase table and it is contain thd ID as PK

Comment: Yes, we checked your code. Your ID from Tablebase is irrelevant. In fact, I strongly recommend you to remove parent class until you learn different ways EF stores hierarchies. But it's irrelevant to the error displayed. What is relevant that `InvoiceDetails` object has relationship to `Guiders` object; but Guiders doesn't have corresponding relationship back. Assuming that it is one-to-many relationship there should be `Collection<InvoiceDetails> InvoiceDetailses`. The best way to learn is to create a database with all foreign keys and scaffold the model

Comment: Wait - you have `Guiders` inside the `Guiders` object? is that intentional? that is bound to cause issues. Like I recommended above - start with a database and scaffold the model

Comment: Yeah I added the ICollection<InvoiceDetails>  in Guiders  table but also same error